# gcc array of "strings" declaration failing

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, declaration

I am trying to write a simple c program, but I am having trouble declaring "string" arrays. The following code compiles without error:

```
#define HAND_SIZE 10;
int main()
{
    char * cards[13] = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

    int player[HAND_SIZE];
}
```

but I cannot make player into an array of "strings" instead of ints. If I do any of the following:

```
char * player[HAND_SIZE];

char player [HAND_SIZE][];

char player [HAND_SIZE][5];

//repeat the above with '= {}' and '= {""}' initializations
```

I get the error:

```
 error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
```

Why is this happening and how can I declare an empty array of "strings" in c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**preprocessor directives should not end with a semicolon**.

Semicolon after the end of `#define` line was giving you the error, This will work:

```
#define HAND_SIZE 10
int main()
{
    char * cards[13] = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

    int player[HAND_SIZE];
}
```

Comment: that fixed it, thanks

Comment: macros _can_ end with a semicolon. It's just that you shouldn't do that _ever_.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you are right. I have updated the answer. Only _statements_ end with a **;** in c/c++, `#define` is a pre-processor directive and not a statement. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Preprocessor directives can end with a semicolon - you just have to know what you are doing.

Comment: but this is really bad practice. Because afterwards, macro users can omit the semicolon and it can confuse readers & IDEs...